# jqPlot donut change data

Tags: javascript, jquery, plot, jqplot

I'm using jqPlot plugin for draw a some plots. I got a problem when I decided to change data of plot, but I can't find a function that can do this. Anyone knows what function can help me?

Here is my code:

```
var musica = [
    ['IVA', 16],
    ['Tienda', 40.2],
    ['Discogr&aacute;fica', 22.4],
    ['Distribuidor', 4],
    ['La fabricaci&oacute;n', 4],
    ['Derechos del autor', 4],
    ['Royalty para el artista', 9.4]
];
var plot1 = $.jqplot ('grafico_musica', [musica],
    {
        title: "M&uacute;sica",
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.PieRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                dataLabelFormatString:'%.1f%',
                showDataLabels: true
            }
        },
        legend: {
            show:true,
            location: 'e'
        },
        highlighter: {
            show: true,
            formatString:'%s',
            tooltipLocation:'sw',
            useAxesFormatters: false
        }
    }
);
```

I tried to change a data property by thhis way, but it`s does not works

```
plot1._plotData = peliculas;// peliculas is an array previously defined
```

Problem resolved using this function:

```
plot1.replot({data: [peliculas]});
```

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean. Are trying to change the data after plotting. For example, click this "button" to view different data -- kind of thing?

Comment: @AbdullahAAlmsaeed yes, and I did this by this way: plot1.replot({data: [peliculas]});
Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
plot1.destroy();
plot1 = $.jqplot ('grafico_musica', [peliculas],
    {
        title: "M&uacute;sica",
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.PieRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                dataLabelFormatString:'%.1f%',
                showDataLabels: true
            }
        },
        legend: {
            show:true,
            location: 'e'
        },
        highlighter: {
            show: true,
            formatString:'%s',
            tooltipLocation:'sw',
            useAxesFormatters: false
        }
    }
);
```

Add the previous code to a function and call when needed.

Hope that helps

Comment: This was the solution: plot1.replot({data: [peliculas]});
But thanks for respons.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to destroy and recreate the plot:

```
function createChart(data1) {
    if (plot1) { plot1.destroy(); }
          plot1 = jQuery.jqplot ('chart', [data1], 
        {
            title: "M&uacute;sica",
            seriesDefaults: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.PieRenderer,
                rendererOptions: {
                    dataLabelFormatString:'%.1f%',
                    showDataLabels: true
                }
            },
            legend: {
                show:true,
                location: 'e'
            },
            highlighter: {
                show: true,
                formatString:'%s',
                tooltipLocation:'sw',
                useAxesFormatters: false
            }
        });
}
```

Here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/U2xef/

Comment: This was the solution: plot1.replot({data: [peliculas]});
But thanks for respons